# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate ( on Ubuntu) accessing SQLite database error: Permission denied (on Emulator and device, too)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-sqlite, adb

I've got the following issue: on Ubuntu I cannot access app's SQLite database. The sequence is the following:

1. Open IntelliJ Idea Ultimate,
2. Open an application which uses SQLite database,
3. Run app on Emulator,
4. Open database tab,
5. New database (+) icon and selecting "Android SQLite" item,
6. In the appearing "Data Sources and Drivers" window the "Device:" and "Package name:" fields are filled out with right data but "Database:" field remains empty (on Ubuntu). On my Windows 10pro laptop IntelliJ recognizes the database name. However I used the same application on booth machines.
7. When I enter the database name and hit OK, I got the following error message: Data Source Synchronization Error: **Cannot synchronize 'Android SQLite': /data/data/net.sytes.csongi.inventoryapp/databases/InventoryApp.db: Permission denied**

I tried that was described at [IntelliJ IDEA Android Database Sync Not Happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822877/intellij-idea-android-database-sync-not-happening) but didn't work. I also double checked which was described at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/accessing-android-sqllite-databases-from-product.html without any good result (but worked on Windows).

System:
1) Working on: Windows 10 pro, IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2018.2.1, JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 amd64, JVM: OpenJDK 64-bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

2) *Not working on:* Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.2.4, JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 amd64, JVM: OpenJDK 64-bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

Application for testing: https://github.com/csongi77/InventoryApp.git

Please help what should I do to access SQLite database (downloading db to drive is not allowed in this case)!
Thanks in advance!

[image: This works in Windows]

[image: Error message on Ubuntu]

[image: Works on Windows]